# Apache Camel FTP using Simple for selecting directories when polling

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

I would like to be able to retrieve from an FTP which is changing the name of the directory every hour. I have the logic to know which is the name of the new directory and it can be passed in using Simple, but I am not sure how to use the options of FTP to achieve this.

I have tried the following using 2.12.1 but it didn't work:

```
ftp://myUser@host/${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmm}?password=secret&delay=60s
```

Is this the correct way to go? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working, the trick was setting useList to false. Final uri looks like this:

```
ftp://user@host/fixedPath?password=secret&useList=false&fileName=${date:now:yyyy_MM_dd}/myFile.zip
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
ftp://myUser@host/?fileName=${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmm}&password=secret&delay=60s
```

eg the ftp/file consumer must be configured with a fixed starting directory. And then an optional file name. Though this example will only pickup files that has the current date+time as the name, and without any extension.

Though read the docs some more

- http://camel.apache.org/ftp2
- http://camel.apache.org/file2.html